# Вывод UTF-8 в cmd

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, utf-8, кодировка

В нижеприведённом коде в строку responseString приходит слово состоящее из кириллических символов в кодировке UTF-8. **При выводе в cmd с кодовой страницей chcp 866**, вместо нужного слова в консоли можно увидеть только ╨Ю╨╗╨╡╨│ . В чём здесь проблема?

Подключен шрифт Lucida Console, а при смене кодовой страницы на 65001 никакие символы не выводятся.

*Если эту строку сразу же отправить в Гугл через cURL, то он без проблем поймёт что это за слово.*

```
size_t WriteCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string*userdata)
{
    userdata->append((char *)ptr, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main()
{
    string responseString;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://...");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &responseString);

    system("chcp 866");
    cout << responseString << endl;

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

Универсальный декодер без проблем смог определить исходную кодировку и само слово:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как минимум, должно быть `chcp 65001` (это собственно utf-8) и в настройках консоли должен быть включен ttf шрифт (Lucida Console, например). См. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955385/utf-8-in-windows-7-cmd

Comment: @insolor Lucida Console подключен, а при смене кодовой страницы на 65001 никакие символы не выводятся

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45622802/4752653

Comment: @insolor спасибо! В следующий раз учту, что лучше искать на англоговорящем stackoverflow) Может, стоит оформить ваш комментарий как ответ? Или оставить все как есть?

Comment: Я не искал специально на en stackoverflow, я искал в поисковике, просто по ключевым словам (c++ cout utf-8). (*Придумайте кто-нибудь плагин для браузера, который с qaru редиректит сразу на en so*). Можно опубликовать рабочий пример кода с комментариями со ссылкой на оригинальный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий способ. Нашёл [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825492/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-utf-8-%D0%B2-cmd#comment1315923_825492). [Первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575863/how-to-print-utf-8-strings-to-stdcout-on-windows/45622802#45622802).

```
int main()
{
    // Волшебная палочка, которая позволяет выводить UTF-8 в консоль. Пока не разобрался, как это работает
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, 1000);

    string responseString;

    //Получаю кириллицу в кодировке UTF-8
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://...");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &responseString);

    cout << responseString << endl;

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
}
```